# Android unit test coverage is always 0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

First I added `apply plugin: 'jacoco'` in my gradle file.
Next, I activated unit test coverage in my gradle file by setting `enableUnitTestCoverage` to true:

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            enableUnitTestCoverage true
        }
    }
```

I ran the gradle task `createDebugUnitTestCoverageReport` using the gradle wrapper with this command: `./gradlew clean createDebugUnitTestCoverageReport`

The code coverage report is generated but coverage percentage is always 0 whereas I have unit tests and when I run "Tests with coverage" in Android Studio my code coverage is not 0.

I use Android Gradle Plugin 7.4.2 (`com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2`), Gradle 7.5 and Java 11. I use gradle with Groovy.

Do you know how can I fix this issue?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to Android Gradle Plugin 8.0.0 solved my issue. Maybe there is a bug with the version 7.4.2.
Keep in mind that AGP 8.0.0 requires java 17.

Comment: Version 8.1.4 and there still isn't a coverage report unless you specify enableUnitTestCoverage = false